# How to expose base class method/property without changing it?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, typescript-generics

Having

```
export class CrudService<T> {
  constructor(...) {}

  protected index$: Observable<T[]> = ...
  protected delete(id: string) { ... }
  protected update(id: string, obj: T) { ... }
  protected create(obj: T) { ... }
}
```

and concrete classes like:

```
interface Message {
  from: string;
  to: string;
  body: string;
}

export class MessageService extends CrudService<Message> {
  constructor(...) { super(...); stuff() }
  
  public index$ = super.index$;  // Results in null
  public index$; // Results in loss of type information (update: any)
}
```

How can a base method be simply exposed with the least boilerplate, without modifying the implementation?

Comment: What method? You seem to be trying to access a prop (`index$`) that you never initialised anyway.

Comment: Sorry, method or property. And it is initialized `private index$: Observable<T[]> = ...`

Comment: Maybe you should use protected access level instead of private on your base class?

Comment: Thanks @НиколайГольцев, actually that's what I was trying, not sure how it wound up as private in the question. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean but I'll try my best to answer.
Let's say you have this hierarchy :

```
abstract class Base() {
 
   constructor() {}

   someMethod() {
       //boiler plate code
          ...
          ...

       this.abstrMethod();
   }

   abstract abstrMethod();
}

class Concrete extends Base() {
   constructor() { super() }

   abstrMethod() { /*concrete implementation*/ };
}
```

Here `someMethod()` has its own implementation before it makes a call to the `abstrMethod()` which `Concrete` will implement. This exposes the boilerplate of `Base.someMethod()` but also makes it polymorphic with `abstrMethod()`.

Comment: Not sure what you are going for here, but the method needs to be exposed unchanged, so there is no need to do anything else in the concrete class. I am looking for the least boiler plate possible.

Comment: Public attributes of a parent class are exposed to derived methods of that class. Make the method public see if that works.

Comment: To explain my answer, what I was trying to show is that a method in the base class can have its own implementation a long with a call to an abstract method whose implementation will be dependent on the concrete class. Doing this will add specialized functionality to the method in the derived class without changing any boilerplate in the base.

Comment: the whole point is to only make public select methods. A messageService might only provide list, create, update and delete operations, a userService might only provide list and create operations....